# Flipping Book swf file forbidden by apache

Tags: apache, flash

Im using Flipping Book to generate protected PDF files.
The folders contain many files, one of which is called flippingbook.swf.

I get forbidden when I place this on my server.
It works fine when I run on a local apache server, on my desktop computer.

How can I allow access to the swf file?

Comment: are you able to view other swf without any problem? Is it only `flippingbook.swf` causing this issue?

Comment: I have not tested any other files. but moving to amazon s3 works fine. I guess apache config id the problem.

Comment: you should check. Is there any restrictions set in your .htaccess file?